# How can i imrpove my partitions?

Tags: partitioning, lenovo, ideapad

how you doing? I'm going to reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 (using ubuntu studio right now) because i have to update my BIOS. To do that, i have to install windows (i tried with everything, and i couldn't, windows it's the only way). Also, i can find more support to pure Ubuntu, i'm kind of new in Linux, as you can see. So i'd like to ask you about how can i improve my system, here are the specifications:

[Lenovo IdeaPad V330-15IKB](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-v-series-laptops/v330-15ikb); I5-8250U, 12gb RAM, 120gb SSD, 1tb HDD.

I will delete windows after the update, also i will delete this current version of ubuntu studio, and use only Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Thank you!

Comment: Do you intend, after you install Windows and update the BIOS, to keep Windows and have a Dual Boot system with both Windows and Ubuntu, or after the BIOS update completes and tests OK, do you intend to remove Windows by instaling Ubuntu over it? Please click [edit] and let us know your intent; please do not use Add Comment. Once we know your plans, recommendations may be made.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you don't have to reinstall your operating system(s) after a BIOS update. You may have to reconfigure your BIOS to point it to the right place for booting your operating systems, but you shouldn't need to reinstall them.